# CREATE UNIQUE creates duplicate relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My Cypher query:

```
START reference=node(0)
CREATE UNIQUE 

    reference
    -[:REFERENCES]->
    (categories {name: 'categories'})
    -[:CATEGORY]->
    category_user{name : 'user_categorie'}),

    reference
    -[:REFERENCES]->
    (categories {name: 'categories'})
    -[:CATEGORY]->
    category_project{name : 'project_categorie'})
```

The problem I am having is that it creates two REFERENCES relationships between the reference node and the categories node, where you'd expect only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't know that the node with name "categories" is unique by name so it simply creates the whole pattern. 
You could do something like:

```
START reference=node(0)
CREATE UNIQUE reference-[:REFERENCES]->(categories {name: 'categories'})
CREATE UNIQUE (categories)-[:CATEGORY]->(category_user {name : 'user_categorie'})
CREATE UNIQUE (categories)-[:CATEGORY]->(category_project {name : 'project_categorie'})
```

Comment: That's what I first thought was the problem. But then it occurred to me, that if that was the case, it should also recreate the categories node. But it didn't, it only duplicated the relation, not the categories node. In any case, your suggestion works. It also gave me the idea of creating the categories node in a prior query, which also worked. That way I could just use CREATE, which I suspect is faster than CREATE UNIQUE.

Comment: Yep that is faster as it doesn't have to do any checking.